# How do i schedule a task to run at a particular time

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

How do i use TPL to run Tasks based on a schedule. The schedule will be in an xml.

I have gone through task schedulers in this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx

but it does not tell anything about how to specify the time at which it should run.

Comment: TPL is about maximizing the available resource. If you want certain tasks to run at certain time, why not just have a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) that fire each minute, check if the time is listed on the schedule, and run the task?

Comment: Another option is just to use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) so you don't need another service/app to run all the time

Comment: You can't  use the TPL for that. The Task Parallel Library has nothing to do with scheduling the execution of code, or Windows Tasks. It's about multithreading and parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

[`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

But keep in mind that the TPL's main purpose is to address matters of parallelism and concurrency... Task scheduling is viewed as plumbing--largely an implementation detail. If your app is mainly about scheduling then you might be better off using a full-blown job scheduling framework like [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main"). It lets' you do this:

```
Observable
    .Timer(new DateTimeOffset(2016, 4, 12, 12, 23, 16, TimeSpan.FromHours(-17)))
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        /* Do stuff */
    });
```

The nice thing is that the reactive framework works really well with TPL.